# Как изменить state родительского компонента в дочернем?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компоненты Row. В нём формируются строки некоторой таблицы. На каждую строку есть обработчик: по **клику** на строку **открывается модальное окно**, по **клику на кнопку** в модальном окне оно **закрывается**.
Проблема: кнопка в модальном окне - элемент дочернего компонента . Соответственно, не получается по нажатию изменить в родительском компоненте Row состояние **showModal** на **false**. Мой (нерабочий) вариант такой:

```
class Row extends React.Component
{
   constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          showModal: false
        };

        this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
        this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
    }

      handleOpenModal () {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
      }


      handleCloseModal = (value) => {
        this.setState({ showModal: value });
      }

    render()
    {
        return (
                <tr key={this.props.objectID} onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>
                    .....
                  <div>

                    <ReactModal isOpen={this.state.showModal} >
                      <p>Modal text!</p>
<button onClick={ () => {this.props.closeModal(this.value)} }>Close Modal</button>
                    </ReactModal>
                  </div>
                </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Установите аттрибут(prop) дочернему элементу и передайте через него родительскую функцию:

```
<ReactModal isOpen={this.state.showModal} parentFunc={this.parentFunc}>
```

Сама функция в родительском элементе:

```
function parentFunc(text) {
  console.log(text);
  this.setState({childrentext: text});
},
```

В дочернем элементе ее можно будет вызвать следующим образом:

```
this.props.parentFunc(this.state.something);
this.setState({something: "Something"});
```

Comment: Функция срабатывает, но почему-то не получается изменить state. В теле функции this.setState({ showModal: false });  Пробовал добавлять колбэк в setState, тоже ничего не вышло. Причем, если в setState указываю новое любое свойство (напр, showModal2:  true),  после второго нажатия кнопки, это свойство успешно добавляется к уже существующему.

Comment: @Alex Kalinchuk я ничего не понял. Ошибка какая срабатывает? Проведите пару тестов и добавьте информацию о них. Например срабатывает ли setState в принципе или какое значение вы передаете в функцию и добавьте новый код в вопрос.

Comment: код с моим комментарием о проблеме находится по ссылке ниже. Уже 3й день пытаюсь найти решение проблемы и заполнить пробел в знаниях, так что буду бесконечно благодарен за любую подсказку и помощь. https://codepen.io/alexanderkalinchuk/pen/wXJYwG?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Тут дело в том, что происходит всплытие событий. После клика на кнопку закрытия клик всплывает на компоненте Row и модалка открывается заново. Ваш обработчик закрытия должен выглядеть вот так.

```js
handleCloseModal(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
    console.log("newState");
}

<ReactModal 
   isOpen={this.state.showModal}
   contentLabel="onRequestClose Example"
   onRequestClose={this.handleCloseModal}
>
  <p>Modal text!</p>
  <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
</ReactModal>
```